# Does creating dmp files effect program performance?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dmp

A very very long time ago, I programmed in C on Unix systems and we would compile in debug mode to help debug a problematic program. The executable that was created in debug mode was much larger and ran much slower than the executable created without debug mode turned on. Today, I'm working on a team that is programming in C++ using VS2010, and we get the option to create a release or a debug version. We also get the option to produce dmp files even when creating the release version. I've noticed that the release version is much smaller than the debug version (as I would expect) even with the option to create the dmp files turned on. I can't seem to find anything, however, that indicates if creating the dmp files will also slow the program performance as turning on debug mode did many years ago. Have any of you read or experienced any performance degradation by turning on the dmp file option?

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean PDB files, not DMP files.

PDB files contain the full debug information of an application.  I suggest to turn on PDB files for release version of your executable.  If your application crashes at the customer, you can use the MiniDump file (yes, that's the DMP file) to look up the cause of the problem by using your PDB file.

Check out John Robbins' blog at http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jrobbins/default.aspx.  He's the specialist regarding debugging Windows applications.